# Merge lines with regex, with exception to certain lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to know how I can merge lines within Notepad++ using regex, with exception to lines that start with the character ">"

Specifically, for: 
[image]

I would like to be able to to join lines 2,3,4; 6,7,8; and 10,11,12; but not 1,5 or 9. In notepad++, I've been able to select the lines I'd like to join and use the extended find/replace (find: "\r\n"; replace: "") to join lines within the selection. However, I have over 11,626 lines I need to join ignoring lines with ">", so doing so manually is not an option.

*Note: image above shows each entry to have the same number of lines, but this isn't always the case.

Edit: Some actual code was requested, which wasn't initially posted because the ">"'s formatted the text into code blocks. Added quotations before each code snipplet so the ">"'s show up:

> >Boechera_canadensus
>   AACGACTCTCGGCAACGGATATCTCGGCTCTCGCATCGATGAAGAACGTAGCGAAATGCGATACTTGGTG
>   TGAATTGCAGAATCCCGTGAACCATCGAGTCTTTGAACGCAAGTTGCGCCCCAAGCCTTTCGGCCGAGGG
>   CACGTCTGCCTGGGTGTCAC
>   >Carex_pellita
>   AATATGACTCTCGGCAACGGATATCTCGGCTCTCGCATCGATGAAGAACGTAGCGAAATGCGATACGTGG
>   TGTGAATTGCAGAATCCCGTGAACCATCGAGTCTTTGAACGCAAGTTGCGCCCGAGGGACCCTCCCGAGG
>   GCACGCCTGCCTCATGGGCGTTAGAA
>   >Carex_lacustris
>   AATATGACTCTCGGCAACGGATATCTCGGCTCTCGCATCGATGAAGAACGTAGCGAAATGCGATACGTGG
>   TGTGAATTGCAGAATCCCGTGAACCATCGAGTCTTTGAACGCAAGTTGCGCCCGAGGGACCCTCCCGAGG
>   GCACGCCTGCCTCATGGGCGTTAGAA

Comment: Please, give us sample lines, not an image, then we can test easily our solution with copy/paste.

Comment: The problem is that I can't get the ">"'s to show up when I copy/paste, since it's the same character used to distinguish code blocks.

Comment: You may actually escape the `>` with a leading \, see my edit on your question :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
(^[^>].*?)\n(?!>)
```

Then replace with the first capture group `$1`:

[image]

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/yZ4nT0

Explained:

- We match all lines not starting with `>`, using a non-greedy match-every-character `.*?`
- We wrap that in a capture, excluding `\n` (new line)
- Using a negative lookahead `(?!>)` we make sure that we're only capturing lines that aren't preceding another `>`.

Comment: Hm, doesn't seem to work for my data. I'll tweak around with the attached link working example. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
find: (?<=[ACTG])\r?\n(?=[ACTG])
replace: nothing
```